Why are my SARIMA model forecasts all NaN in the DataFrame?
I am working on a cash flow forecasting project using Python and the pmdarima library for SARIMA model predictions. I’m able to generate predictions for each column and print them, but when I try to store these predictions in a DataFrame and write them back to an Excel sheet, all the forecast values are NaN.
Here is the code I am using:
import pandas as pd
from pmdarima import auto_arima
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import timedelta

# Load data from the Excel spreadsheet
file_path = r'C:\Users\Joao Mosqueira\Documents\Previsão - Fluxo de Caixa\CashFlow.xlsm'
sheet_name_consolidado = 'Consolidado'
sheet_name_forecast_sarima = 'Forecast - SARIMA (3)'

# Read the Consolidado sheet
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name_consolidado, header=[2])

# Identify the last date in the dataset
ultima_data = pd.to_datetime(df['Data'].iloc[-1])

# Number of business days to forecast from cell A2 in the Forecast - SARIMA (3) sheet
wb = load_workbook(file_path, keep_vba=True)
ws_forecast_sarima = wb.create_sheet(sheet_name_forecast_sarima) if sheet_name_forecast_sarima not in wb.sheetnames else wb[sheet_name_forecast_sarima]
dias_para_prever = ws_forecast_sarima['A2'].value

# Check if dias_para_prever is being read correctly
print(f"Days to forecast: {dias_para_prever}")

# Number of historical days to be used
dias_historicos = dias_para_prever * 3

# Initialize DataFrame for forecasts
forecasts = pd.DataFrame()
print(forecasts)

# Add the date column to the forecasts
forecasts['Data'] = pd.date_range(start=ultima_data + timedelta(days=1), periods=dias_para_prever, freq='B')
print(forecasts)

# Iterate over each column (excluding 'Data')
for coluna in df.columns[1:]:
    # Select the last dias_historicos business days of history
    temp_df = df[['Data', coluna]].tail(dias_historicos).rename(columns={'Data': 'ds', coluna: 'y'})
    temp_df['y'] = temp_df['y'].replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
    # Replace zero and NaN values with 0.000000001
    temp_df['y'] = temp_df['y'].replace(0, 0.000000001).fillna(0.000000001)
    
    # Check the content of temp_df
    print(f"Checking column: {coluna}")
    print(temp_df.tail())

    # Check if there are at least 2 non-null rows
    if temp_df.dropna().shape[0] < 2:
        print(f"Column {coluna} does not have enough data for forecasting.")
        continue

    # Instantiate and fit the SARIMA model automatically
    try:
        model = auto_arima(temp_df['y'], seasonal=True, m=12, suppress_warnings=True)
        
        # Print the best parameters found
        print(f"Best parameters for column {coluna}: {model.order} with seasonality {model.seasonal_order}")
        
        # Make future forecasts
        forecast = model.predict(n_periods=dias_para_prever)
        print(f"Forecast for column {coluna}: {forecast}")
        
        # Add forecasts to the forecasts DataFrame
        forecasts[coluna] = forecast
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fitting SARIMA model for column {coluna}: {e}")
        continue

# Check forecasts before writing to Excel
print("Final forecasts:")
print(forecasts)

# Write forecasts back to the Forecast - SARIMA (3) sheet
# Write the date column
for idx, date in enumerate(forecasts['Data'], start=4):
    ws_forecast_sarima.cell(row=idx, column=1, value=date)

# Write the forecasts for each column
for col_idx, coluna in enumerate(forecasts.columns[1:], start=2):
    for row_idx, value in enumerate(forecasts[coluna], start=4):
        ws_forecast_sarima.cell(row=row_idx, column=col_idx, value=value)

# Save the Excel file with the forecasts
wb.save(file_path)
print("Forecasts added to the Excel file.")

I expect the forecasts DataFrame to contain the predicted values for each column and for these values to be correctly written back to the Excel sheet. But instead, the forecasts DataFrame contains NaN values for the forecast columns rather than the expected predictions.
I have checked the following:

dias_para_prever is read correctly.
The forecasts DataFrame initializes correctly with the date column.
temp_df contains the correct historical data for each column.
SARIMA model fitting and predictions are attempted, and the model parameters are printed.

I have also checked the following potential issues:

Ensured there are no NaN values in temp_df before fitting the model.
Ensured the predictions are generated by the model.


Unfortunately, this code is still not reproducible, since we do not have access to your source file. Consider sharing a small representative sample, as text.

It looks like this code should be trimmed down to the section that misbehaves according to you.

How would you expect us to help?

This question is similar to: Python- ARIMA predictions returning all NaNs. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
